# Copying root file system from target to host

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scp

I want to copy the entire root file system from a target to a specific folder in the host. When I try this, I just get a README.txt file in the desired location. When I open the file, it says "Download and extract the sample filesystem to this directory."

Does anyone know the problem? Below is the input and output of the terminal.

```
rish@myComp:~$ scp -r comp@<IP Address>:/*.* /desired/location

comp@<IP Address>'s password: 

README.txt                                    100%   62   107.0KB/s   00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows `*.*` matches all, [even if no dot is there](https://superuser.com/q/1193102/432690). In Linux (and in `scp`) `*.*` glob pattern matches objects with literal dot.

There is no dot in `bin`, `home` etc. Apparently the only object with a dot was `README.txt`.

Use `*` instead of `*.*` (or not, see below).

Notes:

- Unquoted `*` may be expanded by your local shell. I don't expect `comp@<IP Address>:/*` to match any file in your current working directory, but still this is somewhat flawed.
- `*` doesn't match hidden (dot) files. This is true in a shell and in `scp`, I think.
- I wouldn't want to copy `/proc`, `/dev`, `/tmp`. For this reason I would get a listing and request other directories/files explicitly.
- [`scp` doesn't preserve ownership](https://serverfault.com/q/371421).

Comment: Do you know the syntax to specify the folders to copy over excluding /proc, /dev, and /tmp?

Comment: @Rish No, in `scp` there is probably none. By "request other directories explicitly" I meant you need to type their names by hand and get them one by one.